# Find the volume of generated solid

Tags: calculus

Find the volume of the solid  generated by revolving the plane region bounded by the given curves about x-axis.

$$ y_1 =e^x, y_2=e^{x/2}, x=\ln(2), x=\ln(3);$$

Having a hard time visualizing this

Comment: You should share some of your own thoughts and people will be more will to help.

Comment: Welcome to math.SE: since you are new, I wanted to let you know a few things about the site. In order to get the best possible answers, it is helpful if you say in what context you encountered the problem, and what your thoughts on it are; this will prevent people from telling you things you already know, and help them give their answers at the right level. Also, many find the use of imperative ("Prove", "Solve", etc.) to be rude when asking for help; please consider rewriting your post.

Comment: $$ V= \pi \int_{\ln..}^{\ln..} (y_1^2-y_2^2) dx $$ Try visualizing what the integrand stands for

Comment: Yes, you are on the right track. Any doubts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You said that you have a hard time visualizing the plane region. I have plotted the areas $e^{x/2} < y < e^{x}$ and $\ln(2) < x < \ln{3}$ in the graph below. The darker blue area is their common area and therefore the plane region that is revolved around the $x$-axis. Does this help you?

Calculating the volume of the revolved solid is relatively straightforward, you only need to interpret Robert Z's answer a little bit. Can you take it from here?

[image: Graph of the defined regions]

Answer (score 2):

Remember (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_of_revolution)) that the volume of the solid obtained by rotating the plane region bounded by the curve $y=f(x)$, the $x$-axis and the lines $x=a$ and $x=b$, is given by
$$V_f=\pi\int_a^b (f(x))^2\,dx.$$
Now you should obtain your result by subtracting two volumes.
Can you take it from here?